# push file by ssh but error

Tags: git, github

```
> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:wiwj1987ww/es6.git'
> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
> behind
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for 
> details.
```

when I push file by ssh ,it`s not work.

Comment: SSH has nothing to do with this error, read what it says:  `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Comment: What's nice about git is not only does it give a nice error message, but it also provides hints.

Comment: take `git pull master` and then run `git push master`

Comment: Derek, do _**not**_ force push unless you fully understand what that means. @peter, I _strongly_ disagree with your casual suggestion to force push. The very term "force" should suggest that it's something potentially destructive.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and the problem is not addressing the real problem.

This clearly explains what is the problem is.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:wiwj1987ww/es6.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
behind
```

What you need to do is check your branch and see have you modified any files. If you don't need those changes,

you can do `git stash` or do `git reset --hard`, caution needs to take while you reset hard and make sure what your deleting is not needed.

or do `git pull --rebase`. This will place all your local commits on top of newly pulled changes.

Already Tim Biegeleisen pointed out this has nothing do with the SSH.